# Rails ActiveRecord belongs_to association not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to render a list of Active Records as follows:

```
<% @workout_sets.each do |workout_set| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= workout_set.reps %></td>
    <td><%= workout_set.exercise.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', workout_set %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_workout_set_path(workout_set) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', workout_set, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

My AR setup looks like:

```
class WorkoutSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :workout
  belongs_to :exercise, class_name: 'Exercise', foreign_key: 'exercises_id'
end

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workout_set
end
```

and my schema is

```
create_table "exercises", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",       null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "exercises", ["name"], name: "index_exercises_on_name", unique: true

create_table "workout_sets", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "reps",         null: false
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.integer  "exercises_id"
 t.integer  "workouts_id"
end

add_index "workout_sets", ["exercises_id"], name: "index_workout_sets_on_exercises_id"
add_index "workout_sets", ["workouts_id"], name: "index_workout_sets_on_workouts_id"

create_table "workouts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "location",   null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

In attempting to render the page I get the following error

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

When I change the path in my template to `<%= workout_set.exercise %>` it renders each row like `444    #<Exercise:0x007fbde9dde998>    Show    Edit    Destroy` which is what I expect.

Why is the the attempted access of the name property causing this error?

Comment: For any one of the workout_set, the exercise does not exists. you can add the try block to handle exception in such cases. e.g workout_set.exercise.try(:name). Hope this helps.

Comment: Also you should take into consideration @Rocco suggestion's below however they are not the cause of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your `WorkoutSet` does not have an associated `Exercise`. You can enforce that a `WorkoutSet` has an exercise `Exercise` in your `WorkoutSet` model but there are implications to that. Mainly, you could not create a `WorkoutSet` without first creating the `Exercise`. If that's what you want then add the following to the `WorkoutSet` model.

```
validates_presence_of :exercise_id
```

More likely though, you just want to handle the page crashing when there is no associated `Exercise`.

```
<td><%= workout_set.exercise.name unless workout_set.exercise.blank?  %></td>
```

That will give you a blank cell but you can do something like this to have a placeholder.

```
<td><%= workout_set.exercise.blank? ? "No exercise for this set" : workout_set.exercise.name %></td>
```

Comment: You are correct, I indeed had some old data in there.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: `workout_set.exercise.name unless workout_set.exercise.blank?` can be simplified to `workout_set.exercise.try(:name) || 'no exercise for this set'`

Comment: @MrYoshiji thanks. I don't always remember to use `try()`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set up the relationship in the Exercise model

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workout_sets
  has_many :workouts, through: :workouts_sets #not needed but good to setup
end
```

or if you're trying to do a 1-to-1 relationship between Exercise and WorkoutSet

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :workout_set
end
```

Also having an 's' at the end of the foreign keys in your workout_sets table (i.e. 'workouts_id') is somewhat bad form. I'm pretty sure Rails will be smart enough to make it work but if you run into more bugs I'd try changing those to 'workout_id' and 'exercise_id'.

Comment: These relationships aren't required as I do not need to navigate from Exercise to WorkoutSet

Comment: It's still probably a good idea to set that sort of data relationship up early

Comment: I disagree.  If I plan on having hundreds of thousands of WorkoutSets I would never want to load them all from an Exercise.

Comment: Active Record doesn't do that. It would load them in a separate query (which where the n+1 query issue often occurs) unless you eager load them (`Exercise.first` wouldn't load all its associated WorkoutSets `Exercise.includes(:workout_sets).first` would)

Comment: I realise it's not an eager fetch.  My point is that I don't see the point in adding code that I never would want to call.  Also in response to your point regarding the foreign key, this was generated automatically from the rails migration `add_reference :workout_sets, :exercises, index: true, foreign_key: true`

Comment: Because it paints a better picture of how your data is structured for anyone else who might have to look at the code. As for the foreign keys, it's pluralizing a singular thing. To each their own though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104483/discussion-between-anger-and-rocco-basso).